# Winscp giving error for delete, move etc

Tags: centos

I can login via winscp to my server I can move around the folder but when I try to delete or even download or upload files it keep showing me this error.

```
General failure (server should provide error description).
Error code: 4
Error message from server: Failure
Request code: 3
```

I tried this command df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      112G   47G   60G  44% /
/dev/sda1              99M   37M   57M  40% /boot
tmpfs                 3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: check whether you have exceeded your user disk quota repquota will display disk quota for all users

Comment: just put repquota does not give me any results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this hit me it definitely wasn't quotas; when I thought to run `fsck` it turned up errors and eventually fixed the problem.

Edit: `fsck` only fixed my problem temporarily; the root problem was inode exhaustion due to a runaway process. Try `df –i` to find out if that's your issue and delete whatever you need to.